# JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0 and custom components

Tags: java, javafx, classpath, fxml, scenebuilder

I know that there is already questions like this, but i still cannot solve my problem (and a lot of people too AFAIK).

I'm trying to open fxml files containg my custom components with Scene Builder, and i cannot solve the problem with ClassNotFoundException.

I tried to use scenebuilder-classpath-element instruction with different pathes to my component classes. I also tried to import my custom components using Scene Builder import function. Seems that it was imported successfully (i can see it in custom components list), but the problem still exists (i'm still getting ClassNotFoundE) :(

Is there any way to fix it? I cannot belive that this problem cannot be fixed x|

Comment: The reason I down-voted is that, if you have already done some research for similar questions, and the answers to those did not suffice, then it is nice to provide links to some of those questions and explanations as to why they do not address your issues.

Comment: I understand. I'll take this into account. And thank you for that similar question you provided. I did't see it. I've almost solved my problem,